# Indexing words of a text

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have text who looks like this

> *mmm* we have a dog
>   *ppp* we are going home
>   *SSS* we have gone home

In this text the text between `*` is the reference to a book with page nr and line nr. In this case I just reduced it to three letters.

I want to create an array with each word as key and the line number as value:

```
Array
(
    [we] => Array
    (
        [0]=>*mmm*,
        [1]=>*ppp*,
        [2]=>*SSS*
    )
    [have] => Array
    (
        [0] => *mmm*,
        [1] => *SSS*
    )
)
```

and so on....

Secondly I want to create an array with two words following each other as key and the line number as value

```
Array
(
    [we have] => array([0] => *mmm*, [1] => *SSS*),
    [have a] => array([0 => *mmm*),
    [a dog] => array([0] => *mmm*),
    [dog we] => array([0] => *mmm*),
    [we are] => array([0] => *ppp*)
)
```

Notice that when two words are not in the same line (as in `[dog we]`) it is the reference of the first word that should be used as value.

I think I found the solution to the first problem. I transformed the text in an array
`$text = array ([0]=>*mmm*, [1]=>"we", [2]=>"have",` and so on...

And then:

```
foreach ($text as $word)
{ 
    if($word[0] == "*")
    {
        $value = $word;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $key = $word;
        if (array_key_exists($key,$dictionary))
        {
            array_push($dictionary[$key], $value);
        }
        else
        {
            $dictionary[$key] = array($value);
        }
    }
    return $dictionary;
```

For the creation of an array with two words I did the following

```
foreach ($text as $word)
{ 
    if($word[0] == "*")
    {
        $value = $word;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $key1 = $word;
        $key2 = $text[array_search($key1,$text)+1];
        if ($key2[0] == "*")
        {
            continue;
        }
    else
    {
        $key = $key1.$key2;
        if (array_key_exists($key,$dictionary))
        {
            array_push($dictionary[$key], $value);
        }
        else
        {
            $dictionary[$key] = array($value);
        }
    }
    return $dictionary;
}
```

This doesn't work becaue of the `$key = $key1.$key2;`. It seems that when the key is `[we have]` (as in our text in *mmm*) and later on the key should be `[we are]` the program doesn't make the difference. In fact each time the first word is "we" he automatically adds the second word "have" even if it should be "are". So this means that in going through each word of the text $key1 is not restaured to zero but each time the first word is "we" the value will be put under the key "we have".

Anyone have a solution for this or maybe the whole thing can be done simplier?

PS I hope I didn't forgot to many `{}` I'm typing this on an small screen without a good overview

Comment: Can you try to reduce your code? You don't need to check if the key already exists in an `Array`, just write `$dictionary[$key][] = $value` instead of the if-block with `array_key_exists` and `array_push`. Next to that, the first block looks incomplete, a missing `}` or so as you already assumed. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code snippet, tokenize() enumerates 1-word tokens and 2-word tokens, as well as their position, reduce() does aggregation by tokens. See if it works in your case.

```
<?php
$text = array('*mmm*', 'we', 'have', 'a', 'dog', '*ppp*', 'we', 'are', 'going', 'home', '*SSS*', 'we', 'have', 'gone', 'home');

function tokenize($text, $initPosition) {
  $words = array();
  $position = $initPosition;

  foreach ($text as $value) {
    if ($value[0] === '*') {
      $position = $value;
    } else {
      $words[] = array('token' => $value, 'pos' => $position);
    }   
  }   

  $temp = $words;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++) {
    if (isset($temp[$i + 1])) {
      $token = $temp[$i]['token'] . ' ' . $temp[$i + 1]['token'];
      $words[] = array('token' => $token, 'pos' => $temp[$i]['pos']);
    }   
  }   
  return $words;
}   

function reduce($words) {
  $dictionary = array();
  foreach ($words as $value) {
    if (isset($dictionary[$value['token']])) {
      $dictionary[$value['token']][] = $value['pos'];
    } else {
      $dictionary[$value['token']] = array();
      $dictionary[$value['token']][] = $value['pos'];
    }   
  }   
  return $dictionary;
}   

$words = tokenize($text, '*mmm*');
$dictionary = reduce($words);
print_r($dictionary);
```

Comment: This produces an array where the key equals 1 word of the text, but my problem concerns mainly to produce an array where the key equals 2 words:Array
(
    [we have] => array([0] => *mmm*, [1] => *SSS*),
    [have a] => array([0 => *mmm*),
    [a dog] => array([0] => *mmm*),
    [dog we] => array([0] => *mmm*),
    [we are] => array([0] => *ppp*)
)

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, it does work. Thanks